# Google Maps Streetview. Object has no method panTo

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I'm having a little trouble with the panTo method with google maps street view (V3 api). Console is reporting that it is undefined:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'panTo'

I have set myPano (the variable used for my map object) as a global variable outside of the doc ready function. I can console log myPano and it's contents anywhere in my functions but no matter where I call panTo it returns the no method error.

Is there an option I'm missing for adding the panTo method?

Cribbed code:

```
var myPano; 

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(longVal, latVal));
});

function initialize(longVal, latVal) {

    mapPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(longVal, latVal);
    var panoramaOptions = {
        position: mapPosition,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        pov: {
            heading: 0,
            pitch: 0
        },
        addressControl: false,
        zoom: 0,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    };

    myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        panoramaOptions);

}
```

Now with any functions I use to change panTo I get the error message. Even if I call the panTo method in the initialise function I get the same error.

Does anyone have any ideas? Any help would be amazing.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A StreetViewPanorama](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama) doesn't have a panTo method.  It does have a .setPosition method.

Comment: Ah!! Thanks so much. That's the little dazzling bit of info I needed.